# What are MongoManagedTypes in spring 3.0.5 and how do I use them?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

Im upgrading from spring-boot 2.5.5 to 3.0.5, and see there is a new object in spring-data-mongodb:

The old implementation was:

```
@Bean("securityMongoMappingContext")
@Override
public MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext(MongoCustomConversions customConversions) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return super.mongoMappingContext(customConversions);
}
```

which needs to be changed to add new object of type `org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoManagedTypes`:

```
@Bean("securityMongoMappingContext")
@Override
public MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext(MongoCustomConversions customConversions, MongoManagedTypes types) {
    return super.mongoMappingContext(customConversions, types);
}
```

What are MongoManagedTypes? I cant find much documentation on them except javadoc. How are they created? Is there some annotation needed?

Edit: just adding the new type in the monoMappingContext() gives error: NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/mongodb/MongoManagedTypes

Edit: I cannot find anything about MongoManagedTypes in the release-notes for spring-data-mongodb version 4.0: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Spring-Data-2022.0-%28Turing%29-Release-Notes

Answer (score 1):

They are just a specialisation from the Spring Data `ManagedType` interface that is used to specify some entities that are taken care of by Mongo. Usually it will created automatically on startup by scanning packages for entities and then added to these list. See [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/main/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/config/MongoConfigurationSupport.java)